# What exactly happening in the decoherence?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, decoherence

I know coherence is when every wave functions in the system is in superposition, so when a measurement is made all of a sudden only 1 wave function is left. Does it means this wave function is already there in the first place but our math can only sample all possibilities due to lack of more information or something physical happened to destroy all but one wave function?

Comment: You might be interested in reading the Wikipedia page for Bell’s inequalities, which address this question.

Comment: Maybe my answer here will help https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150146/is-decoherence-continuous/150166#150166