# Decoherence Tutorial on level of the Theoretical Minimum books

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education, quantum-interpretations, decoherence

I'm trying to understand decoherence and other issues in QM related to the Everettian interpretation. I have a BS in physics, but that was 37 years ago. I've read Susskind and Friedman's book, *The Theoretical Minimum: Quantum Mechanics*, and really liked it, but it didn't discuss these topics. I'm reading David Wallace's book, *The Emergent Multiverse*, but I'm struggling with it. Can anyone suggest a good treatment of decoherence on a similar level to the Theoretical Minimum books? Or anything else that would be a bridge between TTM:QM and Wallace's book?

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4284/a-tutorial-explanation-of-decoherence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand about decoherence I learned mainly from this paper:

Joos and Zeh, The emergence of classical properties through interaction with the environment, Z Phys B 59 (1985) 223.

It's long but somewhat readable.

Another treatment is in this book:

Pade, Quantum Mechanics for Pedestrians, vol. 2

See ch. 24. I found it a little abstract and hard to absorb, but it is intended as a pedagogical treatment.

Unfortunately neither of these is open access, and neither is easy going. You can get them (probably in violation of your country's copyright laws) through sci-hub and Library Genesis. I would love to see a super-super-super-simple presentation that was open access.